# TranslateTransform on a WPF Slidercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, slider

I am trying to make it so that when the user holds down the left mouse button the slider control appears where the mouse is positioned and the user can move the slider control left/right. Once the left mouse button is removed it will pass the value into a method. I am completely stuck on this. I have the slider control built, with a default position (the position can vary).

I have tried the following code to get the slider control to move to the mouses position but it does not do anything:

```
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
          TranslateTransform currentTransform = new TranslateTransform();
          currentTransform = slider.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;
            currentTransform.X = Mouse.GetPosition(Deck_Door).X;
            currentTransform.Y = Mouse.GetPosition(Deck_Door).Y;

        slider.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this fairly easily. I modified the slider code to include a name for the translateTransform:

```
<Slider x:Name="slider" 
        TickFrequency="1"
        Value="1"
        IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
    IsMoveToPointEnabled="True"
        Minimum="0"
        Maximum="10"
    ValueChanged="slider_ValueChanged"
        AutoToolTipPlacement="BottomRight"
        Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,-3,51.5,0"
        Thumb.DragCompleted="slider_DragCompleted" >
    <Slider.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform x:Name="mySliderTransform" />
    </Slider.RenderTransform>
</Slider>
```

Then I hooked a click event to a button and used the following code:

```
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        slider.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        slider.Value = 1;

        // get the mouse positions
        string x = Mouse.GetPosition(this).X.ToString();
        string y = Mouse.GetPosition(this).Y.ToString();

        // convert the mouse position to a double
        var X = Convert.ToDouble(x);
        var Y = Convert.ToDouble(y);

        // reset the slider transform and apply the coordinates of the mouse position.
        mySliderTransform.X = 0;
        mySliderTransform.Y = 0;
        mySliderTransform.X = X - 20;
        mySliderTransform.Y = Y;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should capture mouse 
then you should calculate mouse move distance

```
protected override void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   this.CaptureMouse();

    //Show slider here
}

protected override void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   this.ReleaseMouseCapture();

    //Hide slider here and get it's value
}

Point previousMousePosition;

protected override void OnPreviewMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.IsMouseCaptured)
    {
        Point point = e.GetPosition(this);

        double d = point.X - previousMousePosition.X;

        //you can use this value to change the slider's value

        this.previousMousePosition = point;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @NavidRahmani - this doesn't quite work right. The OnPreviewMouseMove doesn't trigger unless i move the mouse around a lot, and even then this.IsMouseCaptured seems to always return false. Also, i do not see how this code moves the slider to be under where the mouse is located at the time which left mouse is down?